# Owl carousel: how to change image based on window size?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I have a owl carousel, that I have to use to advertise some events. Each event has 3 images of different size, based on the user window screen dimension. It is working fine when I first open the page, but when I resize the window the different size images are not appearing accordingly to the window resizing. It always remain the first image.

I don't understand why.

The images I want to display: 1Seventbanner.png (1st event, small img) 1Meventbanner.png (1st event, medium img) 1Beventbanner.png (1st event, big img) 2Seventbanner.png (2nd event, small img) 2Meventbanner.png (2nd event, medium img) ...

```
<div id="at-eventslider" class="at-eventbox owl-carousel">
<div class="item at-event">
    <span id="eventimg1" class="at-eventslide"></span>
</div>
<div class="item at-event">
    <span id="eventimg2" class="at-eventslide"></span>
</div>
```

```
function changeeventimage() {
var eventsnum = 2;  //num of events to display
var pagedimension = "M";   //Medium
//retrive the window dimension by checking some css property:
if ($(".at-megamenuimagearea").css('display') == 'block') {
    pagedimension = "B";  //Big
} else if ($(".at-category").css('min-height') == '240px') {
    pagedimension = "S";   //Small
};
// change the img:
for (let i = 1; i < eventsnum + 1; i++) {
    $('#eventimg' + i).css('background-image', 'url(frontend2022/assets/img/events/' + i + pagedimension + 'eventbanner.png)');
}};


$(function () {
changeeventimage();
$(window).resize(changeeventimage);
$('#at-eventslider').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    nav: true,
    loop: true,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: true,
});});
```

Comment: Why aren't you actually checking the window dimensions instead of deducing it from css values ?

Comment: Hi Peterrabbit, because it saves a calculation I guess, anyway that part works fine (tested in console log), is just the image that not changes.

Comment: The`window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` properties are calculated anyway in the low level renderinng loop, in JS you just have to access the object, there is no extra calculation. And even if it's not related to your problem I think it'd be more readable. And your implementation relies on the assumption that css will be evaluated before javascript, so even if it's probably what will happen you can't be absolutely sure about that.

Comment: Undesrstood, thank you for the hint. Do you also know why the image not changes?

Comment: Your use case is hardly reproducible so no I can't say ..

Comment: actually not hard, you can see an example simplyfied here:
https://codepen.io/frafer/pen/oNqxwpw

you will notice that the css image-background property retrived in console log changes, but the actual image not

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JQuery well so I don't know what could be wrong exactly, but everything seems to work fine when using regular JS.

```js
for (let i = 1; i < eventsnum + 1; i++) {
  const el = document.getElementById("eventimg" + i);
  el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://iili.io/wc7' + pagedimension +'.png)';

}
```

**Edit:**

I can't see what's wrong with this JS implementation, it seems that it might be related to the fact you are setting unsafe-inline style from js, but I'm not sure.

Anyway I suggest you solve your problem very simply with css media queries, it seems more appropriate and it will also be more performant.

```css
#eventimg1,
#eventimg2 {
  background-image: url(https://iili.io/wc7Win.png);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #eventimg1,
  #eventimg2 {
    background-image: url(https://iili.io/wc7Oml.png);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #eventimg1,
  #eventimg2 {
    background-image: url(https://iili.io/wc7Xgs.png);
  }
}
```

Comment: I replaced jquey with javascript as you suggested but when I resize the window the image still not changes.
https://codepen.io/frafer/pen/oNqxwpw

Comment: That's weird it worked fine when I tested it... I'll look later...

Comment: @Francesco I edited my answer suggesting a css/media query based solution. With JS it seems that the loading of the image source is blocked. Might be related with CSP, I'm not sure, I can't see clearly what's happening ...

Comment: Hi Peterrabbit, thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I cannot use css because the image name must be created dynamically by javascript. (The codepen version is simplified because I had to use an external hosting). The prefix name of the images changes: "1,2,3 .."  based on the evnets id, and "S, M, B" based on the screen size. So there are 3 different images for every event, and the events can be a lot. 1Seventimage, 1Meventimage, 1Beventimage, 2Seventimage etc..